# Pushwoosh PhoneGap notifications send to only some subscribers

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Ok so I have been using phonegap for a while for IOS apps. I started integrating Pushwoosh for a new app so I can send push notifications and it works fine.

Now I need to know if Pushwoosh has extended capabilities.

This would be:
My app will have say 50 users and say 5 groups. Any user can belong to multiple groups. Now my app connectes to an external database so I have the ability figure out what groups the user is in. Which means when Pushwoosh registes a device I can also get the device ID and save it to the database.

Now does Pushwoosh have an api that I can call so I can send a notification to only certain users. ie. User 1 is in group 2. Therefore I only want to send notifications to users in group 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Pushwoosh Remote API to send the notification to specific devices. You just need to pass the push tokens to the API call.

The upcoming update will bring tags and filters functionality making server side logic less complex and easier.

Comment: So is it the hardware I'd, device I'd, or the token I send? I notice when it registers that all those are displayed in the console

Comment: During the registration Pushwoosh SDK sends push token as a parameter - "device_id":"DEVICE_PUSH_TOKEN". You also receive the push token in the Phonegap as a parameter to the success function callback (using Pushwoosh Phonegap Plugin - https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications/tree/master/iOS).